# in Terminal on Mac, how do I get back to the normal Terminal window after I go to git config help, for example?

Tags: git, macos, terminal

in Terminal on Mac, how do I get back to the normal Terminal window after I go to git config help, for example?
I have used the git config help application, and now just want to get back to the normal Terminal window.

Comment: Press `q` if the editor open with `vim` editor.

Comment: @SajibKhan in vim I have to enter `:q` to exit and in nano I have to press `crtl + x` to exit

Comment: @Philj0 yes, for `git config --help` command I see `:` already exists by default just need to press `q` to exit the window.

Comment: ok nice, I just remember to exit vim in general

Comment: Great, thanks for your answers, that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same as Linux just pressing the letter "Q" should work.

Comment: Yes, that did work for me on Mac, thanks for your help!